# Можно ли создать второй аккаунт в google play console?

Tags: google-play

Можно ли зарегистрироваться в google play console если уже есть аккаунт? Мне второй аккаунт не нужен, просто на бирже создаю приложение для клиента а у него нет аккаунта, соответственно его нужно создать!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, то на google play console запрещена мультиаккаунтность, у вас могут заблокировать все аккаунты просто. Почитайте политику пользователя у них.

Comment: Ну я же аккаунт не для себя создаю а для клиента? Я только его создаю и публикую там приложение тоже для клиента

Comment: Я понимаю, но алгоритмы гугла если засекут что они связанные, то тогда вы ничего уже не сделаете